# Excluding a subdomain from SSL

Tags: http, redirect, ssl, https, subdomain

i have installed SSL on my website, but i want to my SSL certificate only work on my main domain (not subdomain).
I installed Wordpress on my main domain, and i installed YetiForce on my subdomain

I use following code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://vinyl.co.id/$1 [R,L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} stock.vinyl.co.id
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !stock/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ stock/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But I still can't access http://stock.vinyl.co.id
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://vinyl.co.id/$1 [R,L]
```

Will redirect anyone on `http://` (on any domain) to `https://vinyl.co.id/`. Add an other `RewriteCond` to only apply it to `vinyl.co.id`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} vinyl.co.id
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://vinyl.co.id/$1 [R,L]
```

Note that this will let you access `stock.vinyl.co.id` on http, not *forbid* https (I don't what you meant by "**Excluding** a subdomain from SSL").

Comment: hello @david,

I've edited the .htaccess file like this

`RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} vinyl.co.id
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://vinyl.co.id/$1 [R,L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} stock.vinyl.co.id
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !stock/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ stock/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

i still get server not found

Comment: Could you enable the debug logs for the rewrite module ([RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) for apache 2.2,
[LogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) for apache 2.4) and edit your question with them ?